# Java arraylist of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I have an array of n threads, each one holds a number of 1 to 100.

For each iteration all of the threads needs to check their neighbors.

```
For thread i 

IF    thread[i].number > thread[i+1].number 
AND   thread[i].number > thread[i-1].number 
THEN  thread[i].number--

IF    thread[i].number < thread[i+1].number 
AND   thread[i].number < thread[i-1].number 
THEN  thread[i].number++
```

Otherwise, no change.

Of course no change is being done before all threads have finished their checking.

My question is, if I'm a thread in an arraylist, how can I look at my neighbors?

I thought of the following:

1. For each thread, check the neighbors.
2. Each thread will hold an int field, change it accordingly, 0 for no change, 1 for inc, 2 for dec.
3. synchronize through a buffer (Counter) to count all the threads and make sure everyone is done.
4. Apply the inc, dec or no change.

What do you think?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that you should use a [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) to make all the threads wait for each another. Other than that, to check their neighbor, just give each thread its index in the list, and the list itself, at construction time, so that each can lookup the value his neighbor have.

That said, I don't know what the goal is, but a single thread looping through the array would probably be much simpler and faster.

Comment: The list itself is going to be build from the threads themselves, which mean I have to create the threads objects and then insert them to the list, how can I send the list to the constructor before I have created it?

Comment: Objects are passed by reference. So you can create an empty list, call the thread constructor with this list as parameter, and then add the created thread to the list. Or, if you prefer, you can create the threads, ad them to the list, and then call setListOfThreads() on every created thread.

Answer (score 0):

With ArrayList you can use get(i) to get a specific index. Use get(i+1) and get(i-1) it shoud do the trick